Failed to restart nginx.service: Unit nginx.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: Device or resource busy
nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
Loaded: error (Reason: Unit nginx.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: Device or res>
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-07-20 14:11:56 IST; 13min ago
Docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/
CPU: 18ms

please provide more details:
This error is typical to some common resource (like file or socket) that is in use by another process. which may be a result of crash or multiple instances of the same service running at the same time.
in particular its best if you provide the following details:

ngnix configuration
the relevant part of the logs before and after this error
the complete command line commands and outputs

also it recommended to check which ports are used by nginx (normally these would be 80 and 443, at least.
and attach the output of netstat -nlp | grep 80
